# line splitting using patterns

Tags: excel, vba, split

My situation is this:

I have a workbook in which i take the addresses from column L and paste them into another workbook in column Y

The addresses are like this:

```
Analipseos, Katerinis, 60500
Ermioni, Ermioni, 21051, Alkistis, Alkistis, 21052
Agia, Agia, 40003, skiathos, skiathos 37002
```

1. I want to split each line every time there's a comma `,`
2. Is there a way to split the first three for example taking from `Agia, Agia, 40003, skiathos, skiathos 37002` to split `Agia, Agia, 40003` and the rest `skiathos, skiathos 37002` to be pasted elsewhere for example in column B.

Note: I don't want the commas to be pasted anywhere.

Could anyone help?

I tried this code in my loop: `Sub tst() Application.DisplayAlerts = False Range("A2", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).TextToColumns Range("B2"), xlDelimited, , , , , True Application.DisplayAlerts = True 
End Sub` 
In a separate sheet it works just fine, but in my code loop it doesn' work properly

Comment: Could you show us the code that you tried so far?

Comment: Note that this is not a free coding service: Start using a `Loop` and the [`Split` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function). Give it a try on your own and if you get stuck and errors come back with your code and e real question ([Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613)).

Comment: @ManosAlexopoulos Add that to your question, please. Don't add it as comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to split on the 3rd comma, you can go about it in a slightly different way:

1. Simply replace the 3rd comma by a character you know won't appear in the text otherwise, for example, a `|` character.

Excel makes this very easy to do using the `SUBSTITUTE` function.

So, for example, suppose you have the text `Agia, Agia, 40003, skiathos, skiathos 37002` in cell `L1`, you can replace the 3rd comma to a `|` character using the following function:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(L1,",","|",3)
```

Making the new (substituted) text become: `Agia, Agia, 40003| skiathos, skiathos 37002`

Now, you can:

1. Replace all the other commas if you no longer want them
2. Use `Data` > `Text to columns` and split based upon the new `|` character which will only appear where you want it.

I hope that does the trick!

Comment: My pleasure @ManosAlexopoulos. Since you are new here, unless you are looking for another solution, mark the one you use as a solution so others can know what worked for you when they search for the same problem...